# COUNTIF and print the counted string

Tags: vba, excel, countif

Need your VBA expertise on doing the task below.
I need to do a "MACORS" countif of cities on a column and print each cities next to the number.
I have this code:

```
Public Sub CountLocation()

Range("V2").Select

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastcell = ActiveCell.Address

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "=countif(V2:" + lastcell + ", ""Zurich"")"
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Value = "Zurich"
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = "=countif(V2:" + lastcell + ", ""Armonk"")"
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1).Value = "Armonk"
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Value = "=countif(V2:" + lastcell + ", ""Hong Kong"")"
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 1).Value = "Hong Kong"
ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Value = "=countif(V2:" + lastcell + ", ""London"")"
ActiveCell.Offset(5, 1).Value = "London"
ActiveCell.Offset(6, 0).Value = "=countif(V2:" + lastcell + ", ""Madrid"")"
ActiveCell.Offset(6, 1).Value = "Madrid"

End Sub
```

My problem is that I have around 90 "possible" cities in one sheet and differs from the other sheets.
My code above is printing a city that is not in a specific sheet.

Thank you for you help

Comment: Your code is working with whatever is the activesheet at the time you run your code. Are you trying to specify one or more sheets to run this on?

Comment: Also, use Option Explicit at the top of your code so variables are checked for spelling and declaration.

Comment: Thank you QHarr, yes it is working but, it's returning the name of that city that is not entered in a column.
for example:
2 Zurich
0 Hong kong.

I dont want Hong Kong to be printed as it has no value.

Comment: The code by the way is not Complete, as I need to enter 80 more cities to detect if that city is in the "V" coulmn. by typing ActiveCell.Offset(6, 1).Value = "the city" , if will print out the city name even though it has no value. I only want to print the name of the city that has value. hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the cities in an array and loop that array. Also, have the count range as a range. There is an If test for greater than 0 so won't write out the city if not present.

All together:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CountLocation()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim countRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet 'Change as appropriate

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row 'Update: Extracted this into a variable

    Set countRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "V"), ws.Cells(lastRow, "V"))

    Dim Cities()
    Cities = Array("Zurich", "Armonk", "Hong Kong", "London", "Madrid")

    Dim city As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim startRange As Range

    Set startRange = ws.Cells(lastRow, "V").Offset(2, 0)

    counter = 2

    For city = LBound(Cities) To UBound(Cities)
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city)) > 0 Then
        startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city))
        startRange.Offset(counter, 1) = Cities(city)
         counter = counter + 1
      End If

    Next city

End Sub
```

Notes on the various parts:

The following gets the last used row before a blank cell in column V starting from V2. If you have empty cells before the last used cell you will get an incorrect last row.

```
 lastRow = ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V")
```

Then set the range to count over as V2 to the last used row in V with:

```
 Set countRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "V"),ws.Cells(lastRow, "V"))
```

Define where you will start writing out the results with:

```
Set startRange = ws.Cells(lastRow, "V").Offset(2, 0)
```

Loop the cities array counting the occurrences of a particular city within the count range with:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city))
```

Wrap that in an IF statement to see if count is >0.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city)) > 0
```

Write out to the sheet offsetting from the first paste position by one row each time using a counter variable:

```
 startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city))
 startRange.Offset(counter, 1) = Cities(city)
```

Comment: I have added some more explanation to help you. There may be more efficient ways of writing this but it is a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: wow! great QHarr,
By the way I re ran the code and it's not working now, it says: Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed. It is highlighting  Set countRange = ws.Range(Cells(2, "V"), Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V"))

Comment: I updated code with full references.This assumes you are working with one sheet. The activesheet. You would need a loop if going over multiple sheets.  See for example  Set countRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "V"), ws.Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V"))

Comment: Yes I'm only running this code in one specific sheet. Which really confuse me why it's not working.

Comment: Can you set ws to your specific sheet i.e.  Set ws = wb.Worksheets("mysheetname")    Use the code as it currently is posted above.

Comment: Is the code in a standard module? The worksheet exists? And there is data in columns V after cell V2? The code works for me so i am guessing something else is going on.

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to mention that the active sheet is in a Design Table style, does it matter? I tried copy the data from my column location on a different workbook and it works there

Comment: Post an Image of the table? I have also edited the code to show last row as a variable rather than just as ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row. This will improve the speed and readability.

Comment: Guess what. I ran your code on a different computer and it is working! thank you so much for all the help

Comment: Please accept as answer if meets your requirements so can close off .